# Anchor link doesn't work when clicking picture at my website

Tags: href

I've noticed a problem at my shopify website where there's two pictures with asigned anchor links to them. When clicking the pictures nothing happens. I've tried looking trough the console but I can't seem to find the problem.

Website = https://kuddexperten.se/
First URL = https://kuddexperten.se/products/cloudform-original?variant=39410644713672
Second URL = https://kuddexperten.se/products/ortofoam

I hope anyone can find the solution! Thanks :)

[Picture of where my anchor links are](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gfVza.jpg)

Comment: Make sure structure as: `<a href="URL"><img src="Image Link"></img></a>` Otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Tried to change the code in "main-vendor.js" but I didn't manage to solve it. I guess im too bad at this kind of stuff.

Comment: I am bad too at this kind of stuff too. but can you add your `main-vendor.js` to your question? Also add what have you tried.